# variable in jquery.ajax function: missing : after property id

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

I want to use a variable in jQuery.ajax `{data {action}`

I get this Error:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

if I replace "+id+" with "61" its working perfect.

```js
var id = 61;
jQuery.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/?someurl",
    data: {
      table: "__databasename",
      action: "edit",
      "data["+id+"][persons]": value
    }
  })
  .done(function(msg) {
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you :) "persons" is a string...
And i would really like to understand, why "+id+" is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"data["+id+"][persons]": value` is invalid JS

You cannot have a variable on the left of an assignment unless you use the new ES6 syntax:

```
var dataObj = {
  table: "__databasename",
  action: "edit",
  ["data[" + id + "][persons]"] : value
}
```

vs

```
var dataObj = {
  table: "__databasename",
  action: "edit"
};
dataObj["data[" + id + "][persons]"] = value; // standard, assign after
```

Like this:

```js
var value = "zzz";
var id = 61;
var dataObj = {
  table: "__databasename",
  action: "edit",
  ["data[" + id + "][persons]"] : value // ES6
};
// dataObj["data[" + id + "][persons]"] = value; // standard, assign after

console.log(dataObj)
/*
jQuery.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/?someurl",
    data: dataObj
  })
  .done(function(msg) {
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
  });
*/
```